# Get NULL values in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, null

I have two tables like these ones:

Table `gene_names`:

```
+------------------+------------------+
| gene_alias       | gene_name        |
+------------------+------------------+
| AC148152.3_FG007 | AC148152.3_FG007 |
| AC149829.2_FG002 | AC149829.2_FG002 |
| AC149829.2_FG004 | AC149829.2_FG004 |
| AC155352.2_FG009 | AC155352.2_FG009 |
| AC155352.2_FG012 | AC155352.2_FG012 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

And another table called `gene_transcripts`:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
| transcript_alias  | gene_alias       |
+-------------------+------------------+
| AC148152.3_FGT007 | AC148152.3_FG007 |
| AC149829.2_FGT002 | AC149829.2_FG002 |
| AC149829.2_FGT004 | AC149829.2_FG004 |
| AC155352.2_FGT009 | AC155352.2_FG009 |
| AC155352.2_FGT012 | AC155352.2_FG012 |
+-------------------+------------------+
```

What I want is to get the `gene_alias` from `gene_transcripts` and the `gene_name` from `gene_names`. For doing this, I do (example):

```
SELECT gene_transcripts.gene_alias,
       gene_names.gene_name
FROM gene_transcripts,
     gene_names
WHERE gene_transcripts.gene_alias="AT4G38300_oG.1"
  AND gene_transcripts.gene_alias=gene_names.gene_alias;
```

It gives no results because the `gene_alias` "AT4G38300_oG.1" does not have an entry in table `gene_names`. Up to here, it seems very logical and reasonable.

What I'd like to get (and I don't know how to achieve this, for this reason I ask here this question), is how to get the following output:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
| transcript_alias  | gene_alias       |
+-------------------+------------------+
| AT4G38300_oG.1    | NULL             |
+-------------------+------------------+
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You should edit your `gene_transcripts` example table to match your question. I've created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f0c9/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a left join

```
select 
   gt.gene_alias as transcript_alias, 
   gn.gene_name as gene_alias 
from gene_transcripts gt
left join gene_names gn on gt.gene_alias=gn.gene_alias
where gt.gene_alias="AT4G38300_oG.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gene_transcripts.gene_alias,
       gene_names.gene_name
FROM gene_transcripts,
     gene_names
WHERE (gene_transcripts.gene_alias="AT4G38300_oG.1"
  AND gene_transcripts.gene_alias=gene_names.gene_alias) 
  OR gene_transcripts.gene_alias IS NULL;
```

Comment: You can't create an implicit `LEFT JOIN` with a `CROSS JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause without special operators (deprecated in ms sql server and oracle long ago). Have a look at [my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f0c9/2).